# Exclude Object while .values_list if multiple value

Tags: django

In my model I have a value 'type_name':

```
  class FooModel(models.Model):
       type_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

In my Views.py I want to generate a QuerySet with these type_name-inputs from the DB, but it shouldn't have multiple time of the same value in it.

I tried:

```
  FooModel.objects.all().values_list('type_name', flat=True)
```

and get

```
 <QuerySet ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y']>
```

But what I need is:

```
 <QuerySet ['X', 'Y']>
```

Comment: Add `.distinct()` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "*uniqness filter*" over this (that is normally performed at the database side) by adding a `.distinct()` to the queryset:

```
FooModel.objects.all().values_list('type_name', flat=True).distinct()
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT type_name
FROM app_foo_model
```